# Using Google Table inside jqueryui ajax tab

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, google-visualization, google-ajax-libraries

Okay, this scenario is a little complicated, but I will try to explain it as best I can.

I am using the Google Ajax Libraries API to get jquery and jqueryui onto the page, so the top of my page looks like this.

```
<head>
    <title>TBTNet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script>
        google.load("jquery", "1"); 
        google.load("jqueryui", "1"); 
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['table']});
    </script>

</head>
```

As you can see I am also using the Google Visualizations Table API. On the page I have an jqueryui tabs control that uses AJAX to load the requested page into the tab. On the requested page I have the same html head, so the same javascript.  On the requested page there is a google table control. When I run the page under this scenario the tab displays a blank page. When I run the requested page by itself (without calling it through ajax) the google table control displays just fine.

I am fairly new to AJAX so I may just be missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

--Kyle

EDIT: Anyone?

Comment: Can you post the example with your source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this turned out to be very simple, though I still cannot explain why it worked. All I had to do was move the visualizations load before the two jquery ones and now everything works just fine.

```
<head>
    <title>TBTNet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/style.css">

    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script>
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['table']});
        google.load("jquery", "1"); 
        google.load("jqueryui", "1"); 
    </script>

    <!--<script src="_includes/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>-->

</head>
```